# Problem installing applications on ubuntu gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome

I just installed beta version of ubuntu gnome 14.04 and apparently i can't install any old applications such as:

Sopcast 0.8.5

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-sopcast-0-8-5-on-ubuntu-13-1013-04-linux-mint-1615-and-pear-os-8/

or

Acestream player

http://forum.torrentstream.org/index.php?topic=1933.0

is there a way to install these applications or should i wait until they start supporting 14.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Version**:-
**You can wait** until they release a version for 14.04.But **you can also port** the apps to 14.04 by compiling and building them on Ubuntu14.04.

**Long Version**:-
**Ubuntu 14.04 is still in it's beta**.It has been provided only for the reason that beta testers could find and report bugs in it and consequently the developers could fix them.This would give the end users more stable release.

**Most developers would not release packages for beta releases** because *it is highly probable that the softwares won't work properly* and that *there would be close to no users who would seriously want the apps on a beta release*.

So for now, you can either wait or build the software for yourself.

Comment: thanks for the clarification I am going back to eos luna for now until 14.04 catches up.